# PHP json_decode variables not being set

Tags: php, json, curl, sails.js

UPDATE:

Ill be honest, I gave up and did it in sails.js in the end, I will leave this question up in case anyone can see where I went wrong.

---

wondering if anyone can help me out with a bit of a strange one I can't seem to solve.

I have an oAuth script that returns an output of a json array back to my android app.

The issue I am having is undefined index on all the json variables, however if I uncomment the two lines commented in my code and take a look on the browser then the $hdr line looks exactly how it should, its just when I try to return the $hdr in my header I receive:

```
callback://com.herghost.waves?code=&account_name=&refresh_token=&expires_in=
```

Here is the script I am using:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$code = $_GET['code'];
$clientId = "";
$clientSecret = "";
$redirectionUrl = rawurlencode("http://waves-app.com/generate_token.php");
$url = sprintf("https://cloud.digitalocean.com/v1/oauth/token?client_id=%s&client_secret=%s&grant_type=authorization_code&code=%s&redirect_uri=%s", $clientId, $clientSecret, $code, $redirectionUrl);

$fields = array();
$fields_string = "";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$json = json_decode($result, TRUE);
//print_r($json);
if (empty($code)) $code = '';
if (empty($name)) $name = '';
if (empty($refresh)) $refresh = '';
if (empty($expires)) $expires = '';

$code = $json['access_token'];
$name = rawurlencode($json["info"]["name"]);
$refresh = $json["refresh_token"];
$expires =  $json["expires_in"];
$hdr = sprintf("Location:callback://com.herghost.waves?code=%s&account_name=%s&refresh_token=%s&expires_in=%s", $code, $name, $refresh,$expires);
//echo $hdr;
header($hdr);
```

EDIT: Other things I have now tried

1) Setting a hardcoded string in the sprintf

```
Location:callback://com.herghost.waves?code=1234&account_name=%s&refresh_token=%s&expires_in=%s"
```

I get the correct code back in my android app

2) Setting a variable manually and passing this

```
$test = 'test'
header(sprintf("Location:callback://com.herghost.waves?code=%s&account_name=%s&refresh_token=%s&expires_in=%s",
            $test, rawurlencode($json["info"]["name"]), $json["refresh_token"]//, $json["expires_in"]));
```

I get test come back in the android app!

I have also checked to see if there are any curl errors by using

```
if(curl_errno($ch))
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
```

No error.

var_dump is definitely outputting the results so why are my variables empty?!

ANOTHER EDIT

So I have tried this:

```
$test = '45678';
$test2 = $json["refresh_token"];
$jsonerr = json_last_error();


echo $test2;
if($jsonerr == 0)
{
header("Location:callback://com.herghost.waves?code=" . $test2 . "+" . $test . "&account_name=1&refresh_token=2&expires_in=3");
}
else
{
    header("Location:callback://com.herghost.waves?code=error&account_name=1&refresh_token=2&expires_in=3" . $jsonerr);
}
```

and my response is:

```
callback://com.herghost.waves?code=+45678&account_name=1&refresh_token=2&expires_in=3
```

Never felt so infuriated over a simple piece of code!

Comment: "callback:" is not a valid URL scheme.

Comment: Can you show the output of `var_dump($json)`?

Comment: @Barmar, it seems to work fine for a return, my intent fires in my app, var_dump shows the json array with the values inserted

Comment: I'll ask again, please show the output of var_dump. You may be misreading it, that's why we need to see it ourselves, not take your word that it has the values you expect.

Comment: array(7) { ["access_token"]=> string(64) "afb653153fd449c744acf5dc9c506c2428e5bc91d07b45cee7e0e68f30108413" ["token_type"]=> string(6) "bearer" ["expires_in"]=> int(2592000) ["refresh_token"]=> string(64) "097377b87fe140a90453456687b08145b7b002de7dadc882827328814aee25ed5d088" ["scope"]=> string(10) "read write" ["uid"]=> int(426152) ["info"]=> array(3) { ["name"]=> string(10) "herghostuk" ["email"]=> string(20) "removedmyemail" ["uuid"]=> string(40) "d6de9517c1293b40345435cf51bc324b609bb37ac1ee8a" } }

Comment: I added a few extra characters on the tokens

Comment: It would be much easier to read if you posted it in formatted form in the question.

Comment: I can't reproduce it: http://ideone.com/9vdY21

Comment: Thus proving my issue :-) Thanks for trying

Comment: I suspect the problem is happening when processing the redirect on the client, not in the PHP.

Comment: Its the PHP, else I wouldn't get a reply at all on the android device, the fact I have the redirected url come through as string minus the variables leads me to believe it is the PHP

Comment: If `echo $hdr` shows the string with the variables substituted, but `header($hdr)` doesn't, something must be modifying the URL in the redirect. PHP doesn't do that.